# JPA OneToOne Relationship (Newest)

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mapstruct

I have a Object Bird and a Object Microchip. They ordinarily have a OneToOne relationship:

```
public class Bird {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@OneToOne
private Microchip microchip;

public class Microchip {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String chipNumber;
private Date dateInserted;
```

Each bird should only have one microchip - but when dealing with animals things don't always work that way and sometimes microchips fall out - so a bird could end up with two microchips.

When retrieving a bird entity I am only interested in the most recent microchip.

Occasionally when searching microchips data it would be a requirement to see all the chips inserted into a bird.

What is the best way in JPA to handle this OneToOne?

If the suggestion is to use OneToMany how do you map the Bird Entity to BirdDTO entity - where the birdDTO entity should only show the newest microchip?

I am using mapstruct.

Comment: It's better to use OneToMany relation and every time get the latest chip.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a OneToMany-Relationship, because "a bird cold end up with two microships" and you want to get "the most recent microchip". Simply model it as you described it and write a convenience-function, which gets the most recent microchip for your bird.

Your structure would be something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Bird {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany
    private Microchip microchip;
}


@Entity
public class Microchip {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String chipNumber;
    private Date dateInserted;
}
```